# How to raise a double to a power

Tags: java

Cannot figure out how to raise the formula to a power. I have imported the java.lang.Math in java also. I just keep getting the Sytax error on "Math" delete this token and cannot invoke pow(double) on the primitive data type double errors

This is the formula assuming a 30 year loan

Annuity Factor = (0.003125*(1+0.003125)^360)/(((1+0.003125)^360)-1) 
the 360 is 30 years time 12 months to get the monthly payment

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;
public class HW3Method {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // main method for user inputs
        Scanner info = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the starting annual rate as a percent (n.nnn)");
        double startRate = info.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter the ending annual rate as a percent (n.nnn)");
        double endRate  = info.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter the annual intrest rate increments as a percent (n.nnn)");
        double rateIncrease = info.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter the first term in years for calculating payments");
        double firstTerm = info.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter the last term in years for calculating payments");
        double lastTerm = info.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter the term increment in years");
        int termIncrement = info.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the loan amount");
        double loanAmount = info.nextDouble();
        double mtp = firstTerm * 12;

    }

    public double calcAnnuity(double mtp ) {
        double annuityFactor = (0.003125*(1+0.003125)Math.pow(mtp));

        return annuityFactor;
    }

}
```

Comment: wait, `(0.003125*(1+0.003125)Math.pow(mtp))` does not marked in red in your IDE? and [`Math.pow(double, double)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow(double,%20double)) had two doubles as parameter.

Comment: `double annuityFactor = (0.003125*Math.pow((1.0+0.003125),mtp));`

Comment: Yes it does but only "(1+0.003125)Math.pow(mtp))" im not sure if i should be putting something else inside the constrictor for calcAnnuity

Comment: @RedaMeskali I am really sad at myself .... that it was that simple thank you.

Comment: You don't need to import anything from `java.lang`

Answer (score 1):

### Explanation

You are using the method `Math.pow` wrong. It wants two arguments, the base and the exponent. You wrote:

```
0.003125 * (1 + 0.003125) Math.pow(mtp)
```

But you need to write:

```
0.003125 * Math.pow(1.0 + 0.003125, mtp)
```

---

### Notes

Note that `1.0 + 0.003125` can be simplified to just `1.003125`, so:

```
0.003125 * Math.pow(1.003125, mtp)
```

Even better would be to store that magical number somewhere as constant, then you only need to change one variable and not many:

```
private static final int FACTOR = 0.003125;
```

And then use that constant:

```
FACTOR * Math.pow(1.0 + FACTOR, mtp)
```

---

### Documentation

From the official documentation of [Math.pow](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow(double,double)):

> ```
> public static double pow​(double a, double b)
> ```
>
> Returns the value of the first argument raised to the power of the second argument. Special cases: [...]

Comment: I see now thank you very much for the feed back. I did not seem to understand that it wanted two arguments and I will try and remember that for the future.

Comment: Ur welcome. Remember that you can always just lookup the documentation (link in the answer) :)